# What version of on-premises TFS supports the concept of Azure pipelines?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

The version of ours is 16.131.27701.1:

[image]

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started-yaml?view=vsts I should see the `Pipelines` menu somewhere. I guess our TFS is too old, so which version do we need and are there any known regressions between the version we have and the one with the pipelines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipelines are comprised of the build and release features, which are available under their respective menus in on-prem TFS. They were renamed to "Pipelines" when VSTS was rebranded as "Azure DevOps".

However, TFS 2018 does not support YAML builds. You will have to use the [visual designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started-designer?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav).

To answer the "What version supports build/release" more generally:

- TFS 2008 introduced a build system that used MSBuild files.
- TFS 2010 introduced a build system that was based off of XAML and Windows Workflow.
- TFS 2015 RTM introduced a build system that was based off of JSON files. This is the first truly cross-platform build system.
- A future version of TFS / Azure DevOps Server will support YAML build.

As for release:

- TFS 2015 Update 2 introduced the first native release management tool. Prior versions had a separate client/server application called Release Management Server. It was first released for TFS 2013, but supported older versions.

So, in essence, TFS has supported builds since TFS 2008 and release management since TFS 2013.

Comment: That really sucks.

Comment: YAML build is still in preview and does not have feature parity with the visual designer/JSON format.

Comment: You seem knowledgeable in the area. Would you mind looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53343111/is-it-possible-to-reuse-the-same-tfs-vnext-process-with-different-variable-group ?